# Use model inside useFactory in Nest.JS

Tags: sequelize.js, nestjs, sequelize-typescript

My question is this: is it possible to work with models in **useFactory**? For example like this:

**crawlers.module.ts:**

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        PuppeteerModule.forRootAsync({
            imports: [ProxyModule],
            useFactory: async (proxyService: ProxyService) => {
                
                // here I need to call method proxyService.find()
                
                return {
                    launchOptions: {
                        args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--mute-audio'],
                    },
                };
            },
            inject: [ProxyService],
        }),
    ],
})
export class CrawlersModule {}
```

**proxy.service.ts:**

```
@Injectable()
export class ProxyService {
    constructor(
        @Inject(PROXIES_REPOSITORY)
        private readonly proxiesRepository: typeof ProxyEntity,
    ) {}

    async get(): Promise<ProxyEntity> {
        return this.proxiesRepository.findOne();
    }
}
```

**proxy.module.ts:**

```
@Module({
    imports: [DatabaseModule],
    providers: [...ProxiesProviders, ProxyService],
    exports: [ProxyService],
})
export class ProxyModule {}
```

**proxies.provider.ts:**

```
export const ProxiesProviders = [
    {
        provide: PROXIES_REPOSITORY,
        useValue: ProxyEntity,
    },
];
```

**proxy.entity.ts:**

```
@Table()
export class ProxyEntity extends Model<ProxyEntity> {
    @Column({
        type: DataType.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
    })
    id: number;

    @Column({
        type: DataType.STRING(40),
        allowNull: false,
    })
    ip: string;

    @Column({
        type: DataType.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
    })
    port: number;

    @Column({
        type: DataType.STRING(50),
        allowNull: true,
        defaultValue: null,
    })
    username: string;

    @Column({
        type: DataType.STRING(50),
        allowNull: true,
        defaultValue: null,
    })
    password: string;
}
```

Unfortunately I am getting this error:

```
[Nest] ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Model not initialized: Member "findOne" cannot be called. "ProxyEntity" needs to be added to a Sequelize instance.
```

Although in the whole application, the models work fine, except for this case.

Any ideas to implement this?

Comment: Can you show the provider related to `PROXIES_REPOSITORY`?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel Yes, sure. Edited the main post